# round corners on a link_to image_tag in rails css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I'm trying to round the corners of an image on my website but I cant seem to find the way to do so.
here is my code as of now:
*index.html.erb*

```
<%= link_to image_tag("new(2).png", :size => "50x50"), example_path(@example, :id => example.id), :class =>'css-style', method: :post %>
```

application.css.scss

```
.css-style {
border-radius: .5em;
}
```

Comment: p.s. I have used a div, but it still didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("new(2).png", :size => "50x50", class: "css-style"), example_path(@example, :id => example.id), method: :post %>
```

You were styling the wrapper link on the image, not the image itself.